# Setting up react-native-geolocation-service

Tags: react-native, geolocation, expo

I am trying to use react-native-geolocation-service located here:  https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service

My app is being built in react native Expo with Windows 10.  The very first set up steps seem to involve inking a library.  It appears as though these need to be done in the native code for ios and android, which I can't access in Expo.  Is there a way to complete these steps without ejecting the project in Expo, which is not sustainable for me?

If not, is there another geolocation option for react native that can work within expo? It seems that every option I follow, including react native community geolocation and autolinking requires ejecting the project.   Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expo offer you geolocation api

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

export default function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);
    })();
  }, []);

  let text = 'Waiting..';
  if (errorMsg) {
    text = errorMsg;
  } else if (location) {
    text = JSON.stringify(location);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/
https://snack.expo.io/@anthowm/3777db